# Storyboard-Animation stutters on first execution

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my wp8 app I have an fixed storyboard animation (1 second at all) with about 20 properties which are animated using different easing functions. Actually it is working really good and fluid.

But the first time I call this storyboard in code behind by:

```
FlipPageStoryboard.Begin();
```

for half a second nothing happens and then the animation is almost over and the Animation is already at the end - so there is a big jump of all elements.

After this the reverse animation (another different storyboard) is working perfectly fine and the FlipPageStoryboard itself is also working.

So I guess, it is initializing the animations on first Begin()-call? Is there a way to initialize this, before the user needs to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there something else that is happening at the same time possibly that might be affecting ability to start animations?

Comment: Nothing. It is actually just a plain menu (in a game, that's why I wanted it very animated). The whole code behind is only about those two storyboard beginnings and like 15 other tap events with a Navigate call. I also did not touch the app.* files.

Comment: Hi. I had this problem recently and came upon your question. My specific problem was asked here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818898/storyboard-animation-using-plane-projection-not-working. If your code is using PlaneProjection that might be the culprit. See my above answer.