# Storyboard animation using Plane Projection not working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a pageFlip animation. Now on swipe gesture `myStoryboard.Begin()` is called.

The animation begins in code, but the screen doesn't show the animation happening. But if i switch away from the window and switch back (say 5 seconds after `myStoryboard.Begin()` was called then the animation is visible (from 5th second onwards) as though Storyboard was working as usual.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation
          Storyboard.TargetName= "RightPageImageOverlay"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)"
          EnableDependentAnimation="True"
          From="0" To="10" Duration="0:0:10" />
</Storyboard>
```

The Image :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="flipViewGrid" >
        <Canvas x:Name="flipViewCanvas" >
            <WebView  x:Name="flipViewWebView" NavigationCompleted="WebView_NavigationCompleted" Source="http://127.0.0.1:2121"  Height="{Binding ElementName=flipViewCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=flipViewCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
            </WebView>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
                <Image x:Name="LeftPageImageOverlay" Height="{Binding ElementName=flipViewCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=flipViewCanvas, Path=ActualWidth }"   Loaded="PageImageOverlay_Loaded" ></Image>
                <Image x:Name="RightPageImageOverlay" Height="{Binding ElementName=flipViewCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=flipViewCanvas, Path=ActualWidth }"  Loaded="PageImageOverlay_Loaded"  ManipulationMode ="All" ManipulationCompleted="RightPageImageOverlay_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationDelta="RightPageImageOverlay_ManipulationDelta"  >
                    <Image.Projection >
                        <PlaneProjection RotationY="0"  CenterOfRotationX="0" x:Name="flipViewPlaneProjection"/>
                    </Image.Projection>
                </Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
```

Update :  I have expanded on the context of Image. How the code is supposed to work is as follows. When `FlipViewWebView` is loaded, 2 screenshots of the left and right half of the page are taken and laid over `FlipViewWebView`. When swipe gesture is detected, `myStoryboard` plays. Below is the code which triggers the page flip animation when I swipe.

```
    private void RightPageImageOverlay_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Velocities.Linear.X > .5 || e.Velocities.Linear.X < -.5) //say
            if (myStoryboard.GetCurrentState() == Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ClockState.Stopped)
               myStoryboard.Begin();

        Debug.WriteLine("Velocity : " + e.Velocities.Linear.X.ToString());

    }
```

Update 2 :Another thing i noticed was that the flipping animation is visible if you swipe immediately after the page loads. But if you swipe say after a second or two, it is not visible.

Comment: Did you mean to let it run for 10 seconds? I was hoping it would be something simple like just an off BeginTime or something but nothing obvious pops out, you're sure the Begin fires off? Might have to share more to find your culprit.

Comment: Show the code for starting the animation?

Comment: @WaltRitscher : I have added the code that triggers the animation. Also I have expanded on the context of the Image being animated

Comment: @ChrisW. I put it to 10 seconds so i could see what was going on. I have added more code for context. One thing i noticed was that if i swipe immediately after the page loads, the animation is visible, but if I wait a second or two then the page is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this on MSDN forums and they replied that there seems to be bugs involving PlaneProjection and that a report had been filed.

In the mean time, I have found a work-around. It seems the control being animated doesn't want to move away from 0 degrees.If you change the `From` value of  `DoubleAnimation` to any value other than `"0"`, say `"0.01"` it will work.